# Simplifying expressions such as $e^{-62\pi i/7}$ and $e^{2000\pi i/15}$. Dealing with multiples of $2\pi$ in the argument.

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, periodic-functions

What are the specific steps or rules you should follow when simplifying the argument of a complex number? I am having trouble figuring out the exact methodology when dealing with multiples of $2\pi$ in particular.

Example problems:
$$e^{-62\pi i/7}$$
$$e^{2000\pi i/15}$$

I have not found any good resources with worked out solutions in general for arguments that are multiples of $2\pi$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind that the exponential function is periodic with period $2\pi i$. So:
\begin{align}
\exp\left(-\frac{62\pi i}7\right)&=\exp\left(-\frac{70\pi i}7+\frac{8\pi i}7\right)\\
&=\exp\left(-10\pi i+\frac{8\pi i}7\right)\\
&=\exp\left(\frac{8\pi i}7\right)
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\exp\left(\frac{2000\pi i}{15}\right)&=\exp\left(\frac{400\pi i}3\right)\\
&=\exp\left(\frac{396\pi i}3+\frac{4\pi i}3\right)\\
&=\exp\left(132\pi i+\frac{4\pi i}3\right)\\
&=\exp\left(\frac{4\pi i}3\right).
\end{align}